# Обращение к целевой функции в цепочке декораторов

Tags: python

Изучаю Python. Написал такой код:

logger.py:

```
import time

def log(foo):
    def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Запуск функции %s" % foo.func_name
        res = foo(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return tmp

def timer(foo):
    def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        res = foo(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Время выполнения функции: %f" % (time.time()-t)
        return res
    return tmp
```

test.py:

```
import logger

class Test():
    @logger.log
    @logger.timer
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @logger.log
    @logger.timer
    def __del__(self):
        pass

a = Test()
a = None
print 'Окончание программы'
```

Выводит:

```
Запуск функции tmp
Время выполнения функции: 0.000013
Запуск функции tmp
Время выполнения функции: 0.000005
Окончание программы
```

Как видно, декоратор log обращается к декоратору по цепочке, а не к целевой функции. Можно попробовать решить это сменой `@log @timer` на `@timer @log`, но тогда отображается некорректное время выполнения целевых методов, да и с точки зрения самого изучения процесса, как обратиться непосредственно к `__init__` из первого декоратора в цепочке?

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141501/) (Рекомендации для работы с декораторами). UPD: перенес ответ в комментарий, т.к. ответы-ссылки не есть хорошо, но статья может быть кому-то полезной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю [[@BOPOH](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh) за ссылку.

Импортируем `functools`:

```
import functools
import time
```

далее в самом декораторе прописываем магию (декоратор из functools):

```
...
def log(foo):
    @functools.wraps(foo) #вот он (it's a magic!)
    def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Запуск функции %s" % foo.__name__
...
```

И тогда выводит:

```
Запуск функции __init__
Время выполнения функции: 0.000013
Запуск функции __del__
Время выполнения функции: 0.000005
Окончание программы
```